# Howl to solve the mistake with array?

Tags: java, android

How to solve this problem? When I restart activity the array works anew and picture doesnt changes.I want to change the picture to follow from array when I restart activity. This button restarts activity

```
Button btnNext = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            });
```

Comment: First you should show us some code you tried, second I really didn't understand your question. What array?...What picture?

Comment: @AndritchiAlexei array with pictures

Comment: What does this have to do with Android Studio?

Comment: Where is your array with pictures?

Comment: Also I don't understand your sentences: **When I restart activity the array works anew and picture doesnt changes.I want to change the picture to follow from array when I restart activity.** Please be more clear.

Comment: @AndritchiAlexei Turns out it's actually in an answer to another of OP's questions. It looks like OP writes code by asking SO how to do it, then copy/pasting the answers.

Comment: @AndritchiAlexei when I click on **btnNext**  my activity restarts and picture in array should changes to follow, but there is problem: when I restart activity array starts anew